# Shared ownership of IDisposable objects in C#

Tags: c#, shared-ptr, idisposable

Is there any classes in C# which provide shared ownership of IDisposable objects? Something like shared_ptr in c++? And if not, what are best practices here?

**UPDATE**

I'm writing a c++/cli wrapper over native lib. And I need release native resources (**MAPI COM interfaces for example, so I need determenistic resource releasing**).

Native part:

```
//Message.h
class Message
{ ... };

//MessageSet.h
class MessageSet
{
  ...
  class iterator : public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, Message*>
  {
  ...
  public:
    Message* operator*();
    bool operator!=(const iterator& that);
    iterator& operator++();
  };
  iterator begin();
  iterator end();
};
```

Managed part (c++/cli):

```cpp
public ref class Message
{
  native::Message* inst;
public:
  Message(native::Message* inst);
  ~Message();
  !Message();
};

public ref class MessageSet : public IEnumerable<Message^>
{
  native::MessageSet* inst;
public:
  MessageSet(native::Message* inst);
  ~MessageSet();
  !MessageSet();
  virtual IEnumerator<Message^>^ GetEnumerator();
  virtual System::Collections::IEnumerator^ EnumerableGetEnumerator() = System::Collections::IEnumerable::GetEnumerator;
};
```

When I use Message objects in TPL Dataflow (BroadcastBlock block i.e. there are many concurrent consumers) in C# I don't know when I should call Dispose() for these messages.

Comment: what are you attempting to solve?

Comment: Who calls dispose? Is that an object at a higher level that can do it, eg the thing that calls these threads in the first place. Who created the object? Is this happening in the context of an http request or something that can 'own' (or has an IoC container that can own) and Dispose of this object?

Comment: There is a big, big difference.  Calling Dispose() is optional.  If you can't establish a clear ownership of the object and have to resort to implementing your own reference-counting scheme then you are much better off simply not calling it and letting the GC take care of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best you could do is something like this:

```
public sealed class SharedDisposable<T> where T : IDisposable
{
    public sealed class Reference : IDisposable
    {
        public Reference( SharedDisposable<T> owner )
        {
            mOwner = owner;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if( mIsDisposed ) return;
            mIsDisposed = true;

            mOwner.Release();
        }

        public T Value => mOwner.mValue;

        private readonly SharedDisposable<T> mOwner;
        private bool mIsDisposed;
    }

    public SharedDisposable( T value )
    {
        mValue = value;
    }

    public Reference Acquire()
    {
        lock( mLock )
        {
            if( mRefCount < 0 ) throw new ObjectDisposedException( typeof( T ).FullName );
            mRefCount++;
            return new Reference( this );
        }
    }

    private void Release()
    {
        lock( mLock )
        {
            mRefCount--;
            if( mRefCount <= 0 )
            {
                mValue.Dispose();
                mRefCount = -1;
            }
        }
    }

    private readonly T mValue;
    private readonly object mLock = new object();
    private int mRefCount;
}
```

Basically this allows you to have one object (`SharedDisposable<T>`) manage the lifetime of the underlying disposable while providing a mechanism to distribute "shared" references to it.

One shortcoming here is that technically anyone could dispose the underlying value by accessing it through the shared reference `Value` property.  You could address this by creating some sort of facade object that wraps the underlying disposable type but hides its `Dispose` method.

Comment: Note that the OP is intending to share this object between multiple threads, and this implementation will not work properly when accessed from multiple threads.  You'll need to lock around access to the shared reference count.

Comment: @Servy An excellent point.  I missed the multi-threaded requirement.

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/22092381/340790 .

Answer (score 0):

That would a NO.
Best way I found so far is quite clunky, using Dictionaries and WeakReferences. The Dictionary maps the object to it's refcount. WeakReference is used so you don't increase the ref count artificially.

Answer (score -1):

You do not *own* `IDisposable`, you *implement* it, so [.NET Garbage Collector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xy59wtx(v=vs.110).aspx) will call overridden method in your class, notifying about a fact happened.

It's a different concept from [shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr), where destructor is *guaranteed* to be called once last ownership of a pointer is gone.

In general, in .NET, unless you are not using [unsafe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chfa2zb8.aspx) programming techniques, you do not *own* anything, [.NET Garbage Collector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xy59wtx(v=vs.110).aspx) owns it. 
Even when you explicitly destroy an object, the memory allocated for it may not, and often will not, be reclaimed immediately, like once would expect from `C++`.

**EDIT**

If you have native resources and want release them in precise moment, you *can* achieve that by :

1) Implementing `IDisposable` with your .NET wrapper object

2) Inside `Dispose()` method of that wrapper write the code that releases **native** resources

3) In the code that consumes wrapper object, in the moment you would like to release **native** resources allocated by wrapper object, call explicitly `Dispose()` on it.

In this case `Dispose()` method is called, your code executes and releases **native resources** immediately.

**EDIT (2)**

After that is more clear what's the question about:

If you can not determine when `Dispose()` has to be called, I would stay with @Hans's comment: just relay on eventual (soon or later) `GC` call and avoid your own reference counter implementation (especially in multi threaded environment).
Do not invent the wheel, if that is a feasible in your situation.

Comment: A class doesn't own IDisposable, and can implement it. But an instance can definitely be the owner of another instance which can implement IDisposable. If my instance of type A uses a FileStream, then my instance owns that FileStream instance, and must take care of disposing of it.

Comment: @Maarten: I'm talking about memory allocation/reclamation ownership (that is what `shared_ptr` is about). You do not own anything in .NET, you can "drop" instance by setting to `null`, but that will not free the memory or  allocated resource of an instance, unless `GC` decides to do so.

Comment: To add to Maarten's point, the whole *purpose* of disposable is that it *does* provide deterministic disposal of that resource.  You *aren't* leaving it up to the GC.  `IDisposable` exists to clean up *resources that aren't managed by the GC*.  When you call `Dispose` on an object *it disposes it immediately, and deterministically*.

Comment: @Tigran You're talking about managed objects.  The OP is talking about `IDisposable`.  *Nothing* in your answer applies to `IDisposable`, merely the memory consumption of managed objects, which is entirely separate.

Comment: @Servy: the "shared ownership" of an instance is in direct relation of memory management, indeed. The major point of introduction of `shared_ptr` into `C++` is to avoid memory/resource leaks, hence in my answer I highlight those aspects of shared ownership in .NET world either.

Comment: @Tigran, I'm writing a c++/cli wrapper over native lib. And I need release native resources as soon as possible. And wait until GC made this work - is not a good option I guess. Furthermore memory is not the only resource which may be released.

Comment: @DmitryKatkevich: you're right, memory is just an example. the point is, if you need deterministic memory management, `GC` can not provide it to you, it does not have `shared_ptr` concept and I can not imagine how it may have it ever.

Comment: @Tigran `the "shared ownership" of an instance is in direct relation of memory management` No, it isn't.  Sharing ownership of something doesn't mean that that something needs to be memory.  You can share ownership of all sorts of things.  It also doesn't necessarily needs to be sharing ownership of the memory of a managed object.  In this case, the question is *very* explicitly about the ownership being shared bering the ownership of an `IDisposable` object.

Comment: @Tigran `f you need deterministic memory management, GC can not provide it to you` Again, *he's not trying to deterministically dispose managed objects*.  He's trying to deterministically dispose *unmanaged* objects.  `IDisposable` *exists* to allow for *deterministic* disposal of resources.  It could be memory, it could be a file handle, or anything else.  If he *does* want to allocate and then deterministically release memory *IDisposable* is specifically the tool that C# provides to allow for that.

Comment: @Servy: "And I need release native resources as soon as possible. " Read OP's a comment above.

Comment: @Tigran Indeed.  That's a perfectly acceptable use of `IDisposable`.  It's literally what it was created to do.

Comment: @Servy: I see what you're saying. I understand question differently.

Comment: @DmitryKatkevich: do you have .NET wrapper over `C\C++` code and want to release **C\C++** resources in deterministic way ?

Comment: @DmitryKatkevich: I edited my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Tigran, exactly. The problem is that these wrappers are being shared between threads. I need something like "delayed" disposing, when all threads will finish their work.

Comment: @Tigran The question isn't asking how `IDisposable` works.  The OP was the one *explaining it to you* because *you* apparently don't understand how `IDisposable` works.  He's asking how to share ownership of it between multiple objects, which your answer in no way addresses.  He's already clearly aware that he can use `IDisposable` to manage the disposal of a native resource.

Comment: @DmitryKatkevich: unless there is a live instance it won't be called by `GC`, so delay your explicit call to it, as you need to do it **anyway** for determinism.

Comment: I'm not sure what's happening here. The OP wants to share an object that implements `IDisposable` between two classes and is wondering who's responsibility it is to call `IDispose`. This answer and general rabbit hole of  C++ ideas over ownership isn't helping.

Comment: @DmitryKatkevich: If you did not get your answer yet, considering all vibe here, I think a simple code sketch might help here.